# How to get an element within an ng-repeat by its $index value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat, but I'd like to modify iterations if they satisfy some condition. My question is, what is the best way to get those specific iterations that should be modified?

As it stands right now, I've got it working using the :nth-child selector, but I'm wondering if there is a more angular way to do this using `$index`, or any other more angular way?

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<div class="line_row" ng-repeat="x in program">
    {{x.current_state}
</div>
```

**JS Snippet:**

```
for (j = 0; j < $scope.program.length; j++) {

    if ($scope.reader_location[j] == someCondition) {

        // this is the line that I'm interested in replacing.
        $(".line_row:nth-child("+(j+1)+")").css("background-color","red") 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could `ng-class` here based on expression evaluation it will place a class on that element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="line_row" ng-repeat="x in program" ng-class="{red: methodCall(x)}">
    {{x.current_state}}
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.methodCall = function(x){
   return x.current_state == 'something'
}
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
   background-color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-class` with the condition. If the expression of `ng-class` is true, it will add a CSS class, in  this case, I named it `redbackground`.

HTML

```
<div class="line_row" ng-repeat="x in program track by $index" 
                      ng-class="{redbackground: $index === someCondition}">
  {{x.current_state}
</div>
```

CSS

```
.redbackground { background: red; }
```

Here is a tutorial of how to use [ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) in many different ways.

Comment: This is assuming that someCondition doesn't change, correct? In my program, someCondition changes dynamically. Is it possible to use ng-class here?

Comment: Yes. Please check the tutorial link I provide, it gives at least 5 usages of `ng-class`. Also you can use `ng-class` as a function call to do the evaluation in the angular controller side.